# Seed nodejs express heroku app

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, seed

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/smartphones');
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

var smartphones = [
    new Smartphone({
        title: "V3",
        usp: "20MP Softlight Camera",
        image_path: "/image/phone_v3max.png",
        qty: 1,
        price: 200
    }),
    new Smartphone({
        title: "V5",
        usp: "Feel the Real Speed",
        image_path: "/image/phone_v5.png",
        qty: 1,
        price: 450
    })
];

var done = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < smartphones.length; i++) {
    smartphones[i].save(function(err, result) {
        done++;
        if(done === smartphones.length) {
            exit();
        }
    });
}

function exit() {
    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

When I work locally on Nodejs App I could run and seed the data file (smartphoneIndex-seeder.js) that is included the project by running the command line. But how should that be done when the app has been pushed to Heroku, how can I seed the data from there? The app is running but pages that runs by the seed data would not show up on my page unfortunately. Anyone an idea how I could connect the seed date so my entire app would be run properly.

Comment: You must use something like [mLab](https://mlab.com/) to host you mongoDB on server and access it over the internet

Comment: @JavaEvgen Do I have to run command line or only change the mongoURI?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want some sort of pre-boot process. You probably want to write some code that executes before you tell your application to start listening on a port. This code will look at the database, look to see if any data exists, and if it doesn't then it will call some code (such as your `smartphoneIndex-seeder` function which will push data into the application.

Once that decision is made, you can then call your normal `app.listen()` express code.

Comment: But locally I could run that without any error.....by running the command line "node seederfile.js", but when it is being pushed to Heroku I do not have any idea how to seed that file from there.

Comment: As I said, wrap the whole seed script into a function, then you can call that when your server starts up. If you're dead set on running a command then you can use the heroku run command, but ultimately this may cause a deployment to fail if the data isn't there already.